# R FAQ for package tcltk mentions "teacup". What is this and how can I use it?

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit

In the [R FAQ section 4.6 (Package TclTk does not work)](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Package-TclTk-does-not-work_002e) I found the following sentence:

> ... although they [missing Tcl/tk packages] may be downloaded via the Teacup facility

**What is "teacup"?** How can I install and use it?

I am using RStudio running on Ubuntu Linux and Windows 7.

Comment: This link may help you http://wiki.tcl.tk/17305

Comment: @steveb Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately I am trying to avoid ActiveTcl since I want to use the R code in production and the community edition is not licensed for production. It is really unlucky that important packages of tcl/tk are not available as free (unlimited usable) binary files for the Windows platform (Linux is no problem).

Comment: The packages themselves are, but the ActiveTcl builds are somewhat more complex (for a bunch of reasons). If you want _specific_ packages, we might be able to help. Ask another question if that's the case. Plus, ActiveState's policy on redistribution of open source packages that they've built has not been constant. But we need more specific details of what you're trying to do for us to drill down further.

Comment: do any of the binaries [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/668) handle your problem?

Comment: @BenBolker Thx for the good link! I just want to add tktable, BWidget and Img and Img must be compiled using a C compiler. I cannot find out which binary versions are compatible with the installed version of Tcl/Tk of my R version in Windows 64 Bit (regarding dependencies to DLLs, C runtimes like MFC, Tcl/Tk version...). I think I should post a separate question for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teacup is a program that ships as *part of [ActiveTcl](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl)*, a commercial zero-cost distribution of Tcl (and Tk and many other packages) for various platforms. It does package management, looking after the key part that is download, installation and upgrading of packages from a remote repository. It is not open source, though Tcl itself is (as are the majority of packages that aren't single-company-specific).

If you've got it installed, you use these commands from a shell:

```
teacup update-self
teacup update
```

Depending on where your Tcl installation is, you might need to elevate privileges to make these command calls work. How you do this is platform-dependent; on Unix it's usually simplest to use `sudo` for each of the commands, whereas on Windows it is probably easier to create an elevated command shell and run inside that.

Depending on your site, you might need to configure a web proxy with `teacup proxy`. Try without first.

---

If you're using a non-ActiveTcl installation but you have an ActiveTcl installation present, you can still use teacup. You just need to use `teacup link` to connect that Tcl installation to the teacup local repository. This is slightly more complex because you can have multiple repositories on the one system (though I've never needed that).

First, you find where the repository is:

```
teacup default
```

Then you need to link the shell to the repository:

```
teacup link make $PATH_FROM_TEACUP_DEFAULT $LOCATION_OF_TCLSH_TO_LINK
```

---

Making this work with R Studio will be a matter of determining which Tcl installation it is using. If it's already an ActiveTcl, you just need the first part of this answer. Otherwise, you need the second part as well. Also note that pretty much requires that you be using either Tcl 8.5 or 8.6; there are no guarantees for older, unsupported versions.